# How to know if caret is at start, in middle or at and of a text node in js?

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I need to write a function to know if caret is at start, in the middle or at the end in a text node.
In pseudocode:
function handleCaret(){
var myNode=current text node
if (caret is at start of myNode) return 'start'
else if (caret is at the end of myNode) return 'end'
return 'middle'
}

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object. It can provide information abut selection or cursor position. And also remember about text node normalization (it works badly in IE11). Sometimes 1 text line can contains more than one text DOM nodes.